# Strip scripts from pybuild

Tags: python, debian, setuptools, packaging

I need to build a debian package from a python package.
The python package is not under my control so i can not easily change the setup.py file.
It is using setuptools and has a very standard setup.py containing
scripts. But for my resulting debian package i don't want any of the scripts included.

```
setup(
  ...
  scripts=glob.glob(os.path.join('examples', '*.py')),
  ...
)
```

I tried to use `--install-scripts=/dev/null` but since it is in a debian build that means they are still in the package as `./dev/null/script.py`.

Is there a way to control the setuptools install to suppress/omit the scripts or do i need to remove them from the setup.py via some sed magic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to set and restore before and after the build

```
export PYBUILD_BEFORE_BUILD=sed -i '/scripts\s*=/d' setup.py
export PYBUILD_AFTER_INSTALL=git checkout setup.py
```

Drawbacks are that I actually need to sed things out of the setup.py.
Im looking very much for a cleaner solution.